# Bulk message sending with GCM

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

guys.
I'd like to know if there's ability to send customized bunch of GCM notifications in one request to GCM server.
For example:

```
{
"data_to_send":[{
    "registration_ids":"id1, id2, id3",
    "data":{
        "data":"somedata for this users"
    }
},
{
    "registration_ids":"id4, id5, id6",
    "data":{
        "data":"somedata for users with ids 4, 5, 6"
    }
}]
```

}

Comment: My question is: How i can send notification with different information to different customers in one request (may be not like in example)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. GCM has to be the exact json format as Google has provided.